# wso2mi 4.2.0 : Continous Socket connection errors in logs when pod count >1

Tags: wso2-micro-integrator

Environment:
wso2mi 4.2.0, JDK 17, Rocky 8.9(RHEL)

We have deployed the wso2mi with a wrapper in k8s.
Single pod instance we do not see any errors. But when the replica/pod count is increased to 2 we see below errors in logs.
Below errors are printing twice for every 5 seconds.

**INFO Logs:**

```
[2024-02-07 10:23:27,878] ERROR {SourceHandler} I/O error: Connection reset java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.receiveEncryptedData(SSLIOSession.java:482)
at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:544)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:120)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

**DEBUG LOGS:**

```
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,826] DEBUG {JsonReadOnlyStream} - <init>
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,832] DEBUG {JsonReaderDelegate} - #JsonReaderDelegate. Setting XMLStreamReader: org.apache.synapse.commons.staxon.core.json.JsonXMLStreamReader
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,832] DEBUG {JsonReaderDelegate} - #getLocalName. old=jsonObject, new=jsonObject
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {OMSourcedElementImpl} - forceExpand: changing prefix from  to 
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {JsonReaderDelegate} - #getName. old=loggerName, new=loggerName
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {JsonReaderDelegate} - #getLocalName. old=loggerName, new=loggerName
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {JsonReaderDelegate} - #getName. old=loggerName, new=loggerName
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {JsonReaderDelegate} - #getName. old=loggingLevel, new=loggingLevel
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {JsonReaderDelegate} - #getLocalName. old=loggingLevel, new=loggingLevel
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {JsonReaderDelegate} - #getName. old=loggingLevel, new=loggingLevel
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {JsonReaderDelegate} - #getName. old=jsonObject, new=jsonObject
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {AddressingHelper} - [MessageContext: logID=634fdab486ade390d77c61f5a397f27a11a51b39fbe16bfe] isReplyRedirected: ReplyTo is null. Returning false
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,834] DEBUG {MessageProcessorSelector} - Message format is: application/json; message formatter returned by AxisConfiguration: org.wso2.micro.integrator.core.json.JsonStreamFormatter@4c7b692a
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,835] DEBUG {BuilderUtil} - Input contentType (application/json)
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,835] DEBUG {BuilderUtil} - CharSetEncoding defaulted (UTF-8)
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,835] DEBUG {JsonStreamFormatter} - #writeTo. Wrote JSON payload to output stream. MessageID: urn:uuid:6f4c8123-2615-40bf-b526-29431a3987e5
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,835] DEBUG {LoggingNHttpServerConnection} - http-incoming-33080: Produce output
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,835] DEBUG {LoggingNHttpServerConnection} - http-incoming-33080: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,835] DEBUG {LoggingNHttpServerConnection} - http-incoming-33080: Consume input
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,836] DEBUG {LoggingNHttpServerConnection} - http-incoming-33080: Close connection
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,836] DEBUG {SourceHandler} - http-incoming-33080: Keep-Alive connection was closed:  Remote Address : /127.0.0.1:48336
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,836] DEBUG {SourceConnections} - Shutting down connection forcefully http-incoming-33080
[2024-02-21 11:33:41,836] DEBUG {LoggingNHttpServerConnection} - http-incoming-33080: Shutdown connection
[2024-02-21 11:33:42,942] DEBUG {SSLIOSession} - I/O session http-incoming-33081-1 10.255.18.41:8253<->10.255.12.1:49604[ACTIVE][r:][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: Set timeout 180000
[2024-02-21 11:33:42,942] DEBUG {SSLIOSession} - I/O session http-incoming-33081-1 10.255.18.41:8253<->10.255.12.1:49604[ACTIVE][r:][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: Set attribute CONNECTION_INFORMATION
[2024-02-21 11:33:42,943] ERROR {SourceHandler} - I/O error: Connection reset java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.throwConnectionReset(SocketChannelImpl.java:394)
    at java.base/sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:426)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.receiveEncryptedData(SSLIOSession.java:482)
    at org.apache.http.nio.reactor.ssl.SSLIOSession.isAppInputReady(SSLIOSession.java:544)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIODispatch.inputReady(AbstractIODispatch.java:120)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.readable(BaseIOReactor.java:162)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvent(AbstractIOReactor.java:337)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processEvents(AbstractIOReactor.java:315)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:276)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
    at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:591)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:840)
```

what could be the problem?

Tried adding role binding at cluster to service. But still this problem exists.
Not seen this problem with wso2mi 4.1.0, RockyLinu 8.8(RHEL 8.8).
Tried wso2mi 4.20 with RockyLinux 8.8(RHEL 8.8), no luck.

Comment: Can you try disabling keep alive?

Comment: do you mean , uncommenting the below in deployment.toml and change the flag to true ?
# [transport.http] # socket_timeout = 180000   # timeout in milliseconds
# disable_connection_keepalive = false
# connection_timeout = 90000 # in milliseconds.      Tried by changing the value to true, but still the errors keep on printing.

Comment: further update(still debugging): if route tls termination is 'edge' then the error seems not occuring. if termination is 'reencrypt' using a cert then this issue seems occuring. further debugging.

Answer (score 0):

@arunan

In deployment.toml of wso2mi, I have added these configurations to disable the keepalive. However, I am still facing the same issue.

[transport.http]

socket_timeout = 180000 # timeout in milliseconds

disable_connection_keepalive = true

connection_timeout = 90000 # in milliseconds

Logs:

[2024-03-14 07:44:11,406] DEBUG {SourceConnections} - Shutting down connection forcefully http-incoming-133

[2024-03-14 07:44:11,406] DEBUG {LoggingNHttpServerConnection} - http-incoming-133: Shutdown connection

[2024-03-14 07:44:11,406] DEBUG {SSLIOSession} - I/O session http-incoming-133-85 10.255.8.115:8253<->10.255.18.1:54714[ACTIVE][r:r][ACTIVE][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: Shutdown

[2024-03-14 07:44:11,406] DEBUG {SourceHandler} - http-incoming-133: Keep-Alive connection was closed: Remote Address : /10.255.18.1:54714

[2024-03-14 07:44:11,406] DEBUG {SourceConnections} - Shutting down connection forcefully http-incoming-133

[2024-03-14 07:44:11,406] DEBUG {LoggingNHttpServerConnection} - http-incoming-133: Shutdown connection

[2024-03-14 07:44:11,406] DEBUG {SSLIOSession} - I/O session http-incoming-133-85 10.255.8.115:8253<->10.255.18.1:54714[CLOSED][][CLOSED][r][NOT_HANDSHAKING][0][0][0]: Shutdown